# How to index a 2d array properly pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a .xslx excel file into a pandas dataframe.

Here is what it looks like:

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXu5r.png)

Or in text form:

```
         1           2           3          4
3.5 15.48403728 23.22605592 30.96807456 38.7100932
4   17.41954194 26.12931291 34.83908388 43.54885485
4.5 19.3550466  29.0325699  38.7100932  48.3876165
5   21.29055126 31.93582689 42.58110252 53.22637815
```

As you can see there is a space in the top left hand cell that is empty.

The rows are amounts and the columns are material, the values are the prices.

I really don't know how to give names properly for indexing.

If I was to try

```
df.columns = ['Material 1',...'Material 4']
```

It errors because obviously it is wanting 5 column headers as there are five columns.

Really what I want is to label the top left column as amount/material or something like that, but I don't have a clue on how to do it.

I think the best way would be for me to try and transform this dataframe into something like this:

```
Amount Material   Price
3.5       1       15.48...
3.5       2       23.22...
...
5         4       53.22...
```

as this will hopefully make it easier to deal with.

Any idea how to do this?

I believe this is called unpivot columns in excel or something like that????

Comment: how are you reading the file, did you try `index_col=0` ?

Comment: You can also give a name to the first column right in xlsx file, or skip the first row (`skiprows=[0]`) and read with `header=None` then rename all columns

Comment: use PD.melt()  to collapse your columns into a single variable columns, than rename the column names.    

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: I haven't tried the melt but the other suggestions did not work :(

Comment: I guess you want `stack()`

Comment: @anky_91 I tried what you suggested but I still couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you have read the excel file but if all you wanted is to rename your columns then you can set column names while reading the excel itself.
Supposing my file name is MyExcelFile.xlsx and the columns names that are there 'Amount','Material_1','Material_2','Material_3' and 'Material_4' then I will read it as follows. If these column names do not exist (in the excel) then you have to pass header=None explicitly.

```py
MyDF = pd.read_excel('/FullPathToYourExcelFile/MyExcelFile.xlsx', names=['Amount','Material_1','Material_2','Material_3','Material_4'], header=None)
```

The output is as below.

[image: Output of the reading]

See the documentation here (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). If you have already done it, as I have suggested above, then I am sorry I have underestimated your problem requirements. All the best